# same name objects accessibility within scope

Tags: python

I would like to be able to do this in same scope, if possible:

```
class blah(object):
    def test(self):
        print 'test'

blah = blah() #global

def test(blah='test')
    print blah
    print 'test 2:' + blah.test()

test()
```

Thanks for any feedback.

*Looking for possible way (hack or otherwise) to make "blah" execute "test()" without changing the parameter "blah".

Comment: Please formulate it as a question. Now it looks like it is a page from you scrapbook. What do you want? Why can't you do it, what is the problem?

Comment: I knew what I wanted, and Cody Piersall knew exactly what my question was, and he answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the parameter `blah` into the function `test`, there is no way to access the global instance of `blah`.  This is the best I can do for you.

```
class Blah(object): # following Python naming conventions, capitalize the class 
    def test(self):
        print 'test'

# now this won't shadow the class definition.
blah = Blah() #global

# you have to be able to differentiate between the function's scope
# and global.  If you name the parameter blah, you cannot access the 
# blah in the global scope.  I renamed it some_blah.
def test(some_blah='test')
    print some_blah
    print 'test 2:' + blah.test()

test()
```

Comment: thanks, I already know this. What I was looking for is a workaround to modify the custom "blah", so it can execute "test()", without modifying the blah parameter. This doesn't seem possible in that case. Thanks again!